# SpeechRecognition doesn't work after debugging

Tags: kivy

I tried use SpeechRecognition with the follow function:

```
def on_listen():
r  = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    try:
        print("Dites quelques choses...")
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout = 4)
    except:
        print('Rien dit')
        return
try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'fr')
    print(" Vous avez dit: " + text)
    text = text
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("On est mal à comprendre ce que vous avez dit !")
    text = ''
except sr.RequestError as e:
    text = ''
    print("Besoin de connexion internet !")
return textenter code here
```

List item

In my PC it works fine but after debugging it doesn't work

---

requirements = kivy==2.0.0, kivymd==0.104.2,python3,pyjnius,PyAudio,****

android.permissions = CAMERA,INTERNET,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,RECORD_AUDIO

---

In my log:
09-24 16:46:11.453 23801 23836 I python  :    File

```
"/home/gence/Bureau/Python_to_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/agenda/kivy/app.py", line 950, in run
09-24 16:46:11.455 23801 23836 I python  :    File "/home/gence/Bureau/Python_to_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/agenda/kivy/base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
09-24 16:46:11.456 23801 23836 I python  :    File "/home/gence/Bureau/Python_to_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/agenda/kivy/base.py", line 347, in mainloop
09-24 16:46:11.457 23801 23836 I python  :    File "/home/gence/Bureau/Python_to_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/agenda/kivy/base.py", line 387, in idle
09-24 16:46:11.459 23801 23836 I python  :    File "/home/gence/Bureau/Python_to_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/agenda/kivy/clock.py", line 733, in tick
09-24 16:46:11.460 23801 23836 I python  :    File "/home/gence/Bureau/Python_to_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/agenda/kivy/clock.py", line 776, in post_idle
09-24 16:46:11.461 23801 23836 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 616, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
09-24 16:46:11.463 23801 23836 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 649, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
09-24 16:46:11.464 23801 23836 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 645, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
09-24 16:46:11.465 23801 23836 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
09-24 16:46:11.466 23801 23836 I python  :    File "/home/gence/Bureau/Python_to_apk/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 91, in to_listen
09-24 16:46:11.467 23801 23836 I python  :    File "/home/gence/Bureau/Python_to_apk/.buildozer/android/app/Methode.py", line 118, in on_listen
09-24 16:46:11.468 23801 23836 I python  :    File "/home/gence/Bureau/Python_to_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/agenda/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
09-24 16:46:11.470 23801 23836 I python  :    File "/home/gence/Bureau/Python_to_apk/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/agenda/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
09-24 16:46:11.471 23801 23836 I python  :  AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
09-24 16:46:11.471 23801 23836 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I need Help please !

Answer (score 0):

When you are compiling the app buildozer cannot find a recipe for pyaudio to compile and hence silently fails and skips over it. So in reality pyaudio is not even bundled into your apk and why you are getting that error. As of now there is no rescipe for pyadio and as for as I know no is one working on making one. You can attempt to make your own recipe of I would suggest to change your library for speech recognition.
How to make recipe:https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/

Other alternative to speed recog that work on android:https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#plyer.facades.STT