# How to create a kivy application, that takes microphone input any plays it back in real time?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I want to create an application in kivy. The user should press a button and then it takes the microphone input and plays it back in real-time on my android phone. I have managed to create an app that can get the audio input and save it to a file, but I couldn't play the microphone input back in real-time WITHOUT savying any file. I am doing this, because I want to create a kivy audio-based chat app with python and sockets.
I am using `buildozer` to export my kivy app as an .apk file.

Here is the code for recording an audio file (not what I want):

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.clock import Clock 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch 
from jnius import autoclass 
Builder.load_string('''
<AudioTool>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: display_label
        text: '00:00'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .2
        TextInput:
            id: user_input
            text: '5'
            disabled: duration_switch.active == False #TUT 3 IF SWITCH IS OFF TEXTINPUT IS DISABLED 
            on_text: root.enforce_numeric()
              
        Switch:
            id: duration_switch
                        
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: start_button
            text: 'Start Recording'
            on_release: root.startRecording_clock()
 
        Button:
            id: stop_button
            text: 'Stop Recording'
            on_release: root.stopRecording()
            disabled: True
''')
 
class MyRecorder:
    def __init__(self):
        '''Recorder object To access Android Hardware'''
        self.MediaRecorder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder')
        self.AudioSource = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioSource')
        self.OutputFormat = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$OutputFormat')
        self.AudioEncoder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioEncoder')
 
        # create out recorder
        self.mRecorder = self.MediaRecorder()
        self.mRecorder.setAudioSource(self.AudioSource.MIC)
        self.mRecorder.setOutputFormat(self.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
        self.mRecorder.setOutputFile('/sdcard/MYAUDIO.3gp')
        self.mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(self.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
        self.mRecorder.prepare()
 
 
 
class AudioApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AudioTool()
 
 
 
class AudioTool(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AudioTool, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.start_button = self.ids['start_button']
        self.stop_button = self.ids['stop_button']
        self.display_label = self.ids['display_label']
        self.switch = self.ids['duration_switch'] # Tutorial 3
        self.user_input = self.ids['user_input']
            
 
    def enforce_numeric(self): 
        '''Make sure the textinput only accepts numbers'''
        if self.user_input.text.isdigit() == False: 
            digit_list = [num for num in self.user_input.text if num.isdigit()]
            self.user_input.text = "".join(digit_list)
 
    def startRecording_clock(self):
        
        self.mins = 0 #Reset the minutes
        self.zero = 1 # Reset if the function gets called more than once
        self.duration = int(self.user_input.text) #Take the input from the user and convert to a number
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.updateDisplay, 1)
        self.start_button.disabled = True # Prevents the user from clicking start again which may crash the program
        self.stop_button.disabled = False
        self.switch.disabled = True #TUT Switch disabled when start is pressed
        Clock.schedule_once(self.startRecording) ## NEW start the recording 
    
    def startRecording(self, dt): #NEW start the recorder
        self.r = MyRecorder()
        self.r.mRecorder.start()
    
    def stopRecording(self):
    
        Clock.unschedule(self.updateDisplay)
        self.r.mRecorder.stop() #NEW RECORDER VID 6
        self.r.mRecorder.release() #NEW RECORDER VID 6
        
        Clock.unschedule(self.startRecording) #NEW stop the recording of audio VID 6 
        self.display_label.text = 'Finished Recording!'
        self.start_button.disabled = False
        self.stop_button.disabled = True #TUT 3
        self.switch.disabled = False #TUT 3 re enable the switch
         
    def updateDisplay(self,dt):   
        if self.switch.active == False:
            if self.zero < 60 and len(str(self.zero)) == 1:
                self.display_label.text = '0' + str(self.mins) + ':0' + str(self.zero)
                self.zero += 1
                
            elif self.zero < 60 and len(str(self.zero)) == 2:
                    self.display_label.text = '0' + str(self.mins) + ':' + str(self.zero)
                    self.zero += 1
            
            elif self.zero == 60:
                self.mins +=1
                self.display_label.text = '0' + str(self.mins) + ':00'
                self.zero = 1
        
        elif self.switch.active == True:
            if self.duration == 0: # 0
                self.display_label.text = 'Recording Finished!'
                self.stopRecording() # NEW VID 6 / THIS ONE LINE SHOULD TAKE CARE OF THE RECORDING NOT STOPPING. 
                #self.start_button.disabled = False # Re enable start
                #self.stop_button.disabled = True # Re disable stop
                #Clock.unschedule(self.updateDisplay) #DELETE FOR VID 6 
                
                #self.switch.disabled = False # Re enable the switch
                
            elif self.duration > 0 and len(str(self.duration)) == 1: # 0-9
                self.display_label.text = '00' + ':0' + str(self.duration)
                self.duration -= 1
 
            elif self.duration > 0 and self.duration < 60 and len(str(self.duration)) == 2: # 0-59
                self.display_label.text = '00' + ':' + str(self.duration)
                self.duration -= 1
 
            elif self.duration >= 60 and len(str(self.duration % 60)) == 1: # EG 01:07
                self.mins = self.duration / 60
                self.display_label.text = '0' + str(self.mins) + ':0' + str(self.duration % 60)
                self.duration -= 1
 
            elif self.duration >= 60 and len(str(self.duration % 60)) == 2: # EG 01:17
                self.mins = self.duration / 60
                self.display_label.text = '0' + str(self.mins) + ':' + str(self.duration % 60)
                self.duration -= 1
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AudioApp().run()
```

I have tried the following modules:

- `pyaudio`
- `audiostream`
- `soundcard`

But none of them worked. I cannot export my app with `pyaudio` in it and I couldn't get `audiostream` and soundcard working. I am searching for a solution that uses `jnius` or any other modules that supports kivy (and android)

Comment: To play audio in real-time, you can use the `kivy.core.audio.Audio` class and the `pyaudio` library.

Comment: @iamkw97 pyaudio isn't supported with kivy on android. This error `AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation` will occur. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69316895/speechrecognition-doesnt-work-after-debugging). Thank you though.

Comment: Yeah, `PyAudio` is not supported on Android, and it is not possible to use PyAudio directly in a Kivy app on Android. But to work around this limitation, you can use the `androidhelper` module provided by the Kivy launcher to access the Android APIs for audio recording and playback.

Comment: Would you be able to create a code that does that? I would have no idea where to start.

Comment: An example code has been added. Try to get an idea.

Comment: I see. I'll try to make it work. How do I install `androidhelper`?

Comment: The androidhelper module is included in the Kivy launcher, so you don't need to install it separately. However, you need to have the Kivy launcher installed on your Android device in order to use it.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer?